# Preposition at the end

Tags: prepositions

My phrase is "he put his arm in the door, to switch on the lights."  But should it be, "...to switch the lights on."  I know a preposition at the end of a phrase / sentence is supposed to be incorrect, but somehow the former phrase sounds wrong to the ear, unnatural.

Comment: Both forms (preposition before, preposition after) are very commonly found in English speech. The former ('switch on the lights') is perhaps _slightly_ more formal, but both are acceptable. Any preference for one over the other is a matter of opinion, and thus this question is opinion-based and off-topic. I would be far more worried about 'he put his arm in the door' which, read literally, would be impossible with causing injury and damage.

Comment: There was once a fashion in certain circles for keeping prepositions away from the end of sentences but, as Winston Churchill is reported to have responded: **This is the type of arrant pedantry up with which I will not put.** Feel free to end your sentences with prepositions.

Comment: Note that if "the lights" had already been mentioned, you could refer to ***them*** subsequently  using that pronoun. But if the object of ***switch on*** is a ***pronoun***, you must put it *inside* the phrasal verb, so it's *He switched **them** on* (it's idiomatically invalid to say *He switched on them*).

Comment: Whether either of these forms is grammatically valid, oir is in common use, or is natural, is no more a matter of opinion than any other question of English usage that might be debated. Which is brst is a matter of style, and so of opinion. This question should not be clsoed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of

> - He put his arm in the door, to switch on the lights.
> - He put his arm in the door, to switch the lights on.

are grammatically valid. Fluent speakers should easily understand either, and not think either odd. Fluent speaks might well say or write either.

I am not convinced that either is significantly more formal than the other. I think the difference is simply one of style.

AS [the commenbt](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331606/preposition-at-the-end?noredirect=1#comment627401_331606) by Ronald Sole points out, at onme time some writers on grammar held that sentences with a preposition at the end were incorrect.  I believe this was based on adapting rules of Latin grammar to English, and like other such adaptations, was never a really accepted part of English. Certainly both forms have a long history of usage, including by educated speakers and well-known writers.  The Churchil quote is now a classic response, but far from the only possible response, to one who tries to invoke such a "rule".

Which form is to be preferred is a matter of style.

Comment: Thank You Kindly, to you & Ronald Sole (tried responding as i did to the first comment, but i'm new to the platform & it seems prompt response is required, or you're locked out). i tried swallowing the "jagged little pill" aforementioned as best i could, but with your two comments, it just shows how ridiculous that was... can't tell you how many "with which" phrases i've constructed Just to avoid ending in a preposition. and really the term poetic licence should apply to everything outside actually learning definitions & rules. all else should be free game, as long as it's intelligible.

Answer (score 1):

'Switch off' is a *phrasal verb*, comprised of a verb and a particle (sometimes more than one particle). Not only is it perfectly acceptable to break up the verb and place the particle at the end of the sentence - it is *essential* when you use a pronoun!

For example, you can say either '*switch off the light*', or '*switch the light off*' **but** if you use the pronoun '*it*' to refer to the light, the only correct construction is "*switch it off*".

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct. English speakers use both with the exception of **reverse sentence structure**. For example:

> "To switch the lights on, one needs to (verbal phrase)"

> "To go left, turn left" << also a verbal phrase at the end

Additionally, the first sentence does not need a comma because the second part of it "to switch on the lights", which is a dependent clause. It cannot function on its own.

Comment: ooh, thanks for that extra bit.  will remove comma.